# For loop output when scaling figure in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have been unable to get my for loop to run right number of times with my "figure" when scaling.
The LINES constant here is the scaling "number".

The problem i am facing lies here i think:

```
for(int k = 0; k < LINES; k++){
    System.out.print("*******");
}
```

It is supposed to make a line of * at the bottom.

This is my whole code which produces a stairs figure of some kind

```
public class PP5 {
public static int j;
public static final int LINES = 5;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(j = 0 ; j < LINES; j++){

        fSpaces();
        System.out.print("  o   *******");
        bSpaces();
        System.out.println("*");
        fSpaces();
        System.out.print(" /|\\  *");
        bbSpaces();
        System.out.println("*");
        fSpaces();
        System.out.print(" / \\  *");
        bbSpaces();
        System.out.println("*");
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < LINES; k++){
        System.out.print("*******");
    }
}



public static void fSpaces(){
    for(int i = (LINES-1); i > j; i--){
        System.out.print("      ");
    }
}
public static void bSpaces(){
    for(int i = 0; i < j; i++){
        System.out.print("      ");
    }
}
public static void bbSpaces(){
    for(int i = 0; i < j+1; i++){
        System.out.print("      ");
    }
}
}
```

Any optimizations is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: what exactly is the problem.  You can illustrate by posting your expected output and your actual output

Comment: Your loop print "*******" `LINE` times. So the total number of asterisks will be 7 multiplied by `LINE`.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50868481/java.png
as you can see it doesnt produce enough * on the bottom line.
If i make it produce enough by making the for loop: k < LINES+(some number) it wont be enough if i change the LINES constant to scale the figure

Comment: @all we come more or less all to the same conclusion. what about redoing the exercise in a way that it repaints n/times giving the illusion of the man going up? E.g. 10 steps. 10 redraw and the man goes till the top.... At least we need to write better the code ... Same approach. no libraries and only characters like here. Reply here if can be interested and I create the question as a game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you require 38 stars and you are printing 35

```
38=(6(Every increment) * 6 (No of times) )+2 (first increment is of 8[6+2])

No of times =6 Because indexing starts from 0 (0,1,2,3,4,5) so in actual counting is 6
```

so use

```
for(int k = 0; k <(LINES+1)*6; k++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.print("**");// last star
```

*Output:*

```
                          o   ********
                         /|\  *      *
                         / \  *      *
                    o   *******      *
                   /|\  *            *
                   / \  *            *
              o   *******            *
             /|\  *                  *
             / \  *                  *
        o   *******                  *
       /|\  *                        *
       / \  *                        *
  o   *******                        *
 /|\  *                              *
 / \  *                              *
**************************************
```

Answer (score 2):

To get effect similar to this

```
                          o   ********
                         /|\  *     |*
                         / \  *     |*
                    o   *******     |*
                   /|\  *     |     |*
                   / \  *     |     |*
              o   *******     |     |*
             /|\  *     |     |     |*
             / \  *     |     |     |*
        o   *******     |     |     |*
       /|\  *     |     |     |     |*
       / \  *     |     |     |     |*
  o   *******     |     |     |     |*
 /|\  *     |     |     |     |     |*
 / \  *     |     |     |     |     |*
**************************************

|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_
```

you need to notice that each of this part `|_____`

has six characters so you will need to use six `*` and print them `LINES + 1` times since there are `LINES + 1` `|_____` parts.

This will generate

```
************************************|_
```

from

```
|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_
```

so you will need to add last two `*` manually so change your last loop to

```
for (int k = 0; k <= LINES; k++) {
    System.out.print("******");//reduce star numbers by one
}
System.out.print("**");//and add this line
```

Comment: I have proposed a variant of this question for fun. Motivation. Here we all come to the same conclusion. Taken this way a bit more of design and code clearness will be required. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752559/challenge-part1-adding-dynamicity-to-a-picture-without-user-interaction

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation just  replace

```
for(int k = 0; k < LINES; k++){
    System.out.print("*******");
}
```

with

```
for(int k = 0; k < STEPS+1; k++){
    System.out.print("******");
}
System.out.print("**");
```

The motivation is that each step you add 7 * with one overlapping. This means that you need to add 6 * not 7. You add 1 time more to match the top part (but 2 * are missing: 1 because the top line is made of 7* and one for the column).

Comment: @Tarsem I have proposed a variant of this question for fun.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752559/challenge-part1-adding-dynamicity-to-a-picture-without-user-interaction